# Definition of Variables in Fluid Flow Differential Equation?

Tags: differential, fluid-dynamics

I'm a student who is familiar with Calc 2 and is starting to learn MultiVariable calc.

I came across this article which seemed interesting for Fluid Flow:

[http://www.ipt.ntnu.no/~kleppe/TPG4150/equations.pdf](http://www.ipt.ntnu.no/%7Ekleppe/TPG4150/equations.pdf)

There, this equation is shown.

All the variables are defined in the paper except for A and phi. Im assuming A is surface area, and I don't understand what Phi is.

$${uρA}_x − {uρA}_{x+ Δx} = \frac{∂}{∂t} {φAΔxρ}$$

What does phi represent here?

Comment: After thinking about the units, I'm not sure either. Maybe a constant for a property of the fluid?

Comment: I think it represents the porosity and should be between $0$ and $1$. $\phi A$ would represent the actual area the fluid can flow through.

Comment: Its a law of conservation of some quantity, mostly mass-energy-momentum in physics. Then A is the quantity current per mass unit and $\phi$ the quantity density per mass unit. Later on you see that the ideal gas model is used with mechanical energy p*V  equal the thermal energy R*T in an approxiimate equlibrium state.

Comment: @Nick that seems to make a lot of sense, but there's one problem I can see. On the left side, u represents the velocity of the fluid. If we go with your theory of ϕA representing actual surface area that the fluid can flow through, there isn't a quantity on the right side representing velocity, so we don't know how fast the fluid is passing through this surface area, unless the right side accounts for that in some other way that I don't understand.

Comment: @Roland F, I'm pretty sure that A still represents surface area since later on in the paper, the authors say "Assuming surface area is constant" and then give a new equation where they simply disappeared the A's. I don't see how the ideal gas model has anything to do with the equation given, though I don't know fluid dynamics that well so I might not see the obvious connection.